# How to convert an Jetpack Compose ImageVector to a Drawable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-drawable, android-image

How to convert an `ImageVector` to a `Drawable`?

Let's say I have the `Icons.Default.Public` from the `implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended` package.

I want to convert this `ImageVector` to a `Drawable` object.

Comment: You might be able to create your own subclass of `Drawable` that wraps the `ImageVector` and renders it to the `Canvas`.

Comment: @J. Hegg: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: @Rengers unfortunately not